# Why the probabilities of CNN output don't match?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm training a CNN model with two classes to predict. I know it gives me a probability for one class and for the other one, and I also know I can get the predicted label, but I don't the results given. Isn't the sum of the output for each evaluated input supposed to be equal 1.0? For instance:

```
[[0.2858745  0.85059494]
 [0.2858745  0.85059494]
 [0.6040499  0.5927084 ]
 [0.8403308  0.291448  ]
 [0.04195209 0.95504093]
 [0.79433376 0.21279709]
 [0.79433376 0.21279709]
 [0.01326967 0.9891382 ]
 [0.0153821  0.9867737 ]
 [0.79433376 0.21279709]
 [0.01617167 0.98520505]
 [0.01351487 0.98596036]
 [0.01473185 0.9846144 ]
 [0.00896762 0.9899838 ]
 [0.00936404 0.9893628 ]]
```

Is there something I didn't get?

my code:

```
model_05_01 = Sequential()
model_05_01.add(Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=12, 
                 input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], 1)))
model_05_01.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4))

model_05_01.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=12))
model_05_01.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4))

model_05_01.add(Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=12))
model_05_01.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4))

model_05_01.add(Flatten())

model_05_01.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model_05_01.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))

model_05_01.compile(loss='logcosh', optimizer='adam', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `activation='softmax'` for the last layer, and ensure that your training labels are already one-hot encoded.

Also, irrelevant to your issue, but you should also add an `activation='relu'` argument in your convolutional layers, too.

Last but not least, you should **not** use `logcosh` loss in a classification problem, since it is a [regression](https://keras.io/api/losses/) loss; in the given setting of softmax classification with one-hot encoded labels, you should stick to `categorical_crossentropy` (as pointed out in the comments below, loss is *not* a hyperparameter).

Comment: They are OHE, and I've tried with softmax but the results were better with sigmoid, both in my personal tests as in hyperparameter testing using Talos.

Comment: Yes, it is a classification problem. I'm trying to classify complex DNA sequences. As in the example above, first I used categorical_crossentropy, but by testing hyperparameters, logcosh gave me better results.

Comment: @TiagoMinuzzi The loss is not a hyper-parameter, you select it according to the task. The same for the activation at the output, using sigmoid does not produce a valid probability distribution, so it is wrong to use it in this case. You have to use softmax

Comment: Why when I change from locosh to categorical_crossentropy val_loss increases 10x?
Logcosh val_loss is ≃ 0.0270, categorical_crossentropy ≃ 0.260.

Comment: @TiagoMinuzzi comparing values of logcosh with categorical cross entropy (or any other different loss function) is like comparing apples to oranges; these values are *not* comparable. The ultimate judge here is your *business* metric (i.e. accuracy).